# ArduinoのWebClientの例でEthernet.begin(mac)で固まる。

Tags: arduino

Arduinoのイーサネットシールドを購入したので早速ArduinoIDEに付いているWebClientというサンプルをMacアドレスの箇所を自分のものに変えて実行してみたのですが、
最初に`Ethernet.begin(mac);`でDHCPによりIPを解決するところでもし返り値がfalseなら`Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);`で再度接続を試みるようになっていますが、最初の命令が帰ってこないためそこで固まってしまいます。
同じ症状の方はいませんか、解決方法を教えて下さい。

そのサンプルをいかに添付します。

```html
/*
  Web client

 This sketch connects to a website (http://www.google.com)
 using an Arduino Wiznet Ethernet shield.

 Circuit:
 * Ethernet shield attached to pins 10, 11, 12, 13

 created 18 Dec 2009
 by David A. Mellis
 modified 9 Apr 2012
 by Tom Igoe, based on work by Adrian McEwen

 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Enter a MAC address for your controller below.
// Newer Ethernet shields have a MAC address printed on a sticker on the shield
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
// if you don't want to use DNS (and reduce your sketch size)
// use the numeric IP instead of the name for the server:
//IPAddress server(74,125,232,128);  // numeric IP for Google (no DNS)
char server[] = "www.google.com";    // name address for Google (using DNS)

// Set the static IP address to use if the DHCP fails to assign
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 177);

// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server
// that you want to connect to (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }

  // start the Ethernet connection:
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // no point in carrying on, so do nothing forevermore:
    // try to congifure using IP address instead of DHCP:
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  }
  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("connecting...");

  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("GET /search?q=arduino HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: www.google.com");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  }
  else {
    // kf you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}

void loop()
{
  // if there are incoming bytes available
  // from the server, read them and print them:
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  // if the server's disconnected, stop the client:
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();

    // do nothing forevermore:
    while (true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました。

私が使っていたEthernet Shield 2は新しいもので、IDEが古かったため動かなかったようです。

Answer (score 1):

[http://www.google.com/search?q=arduinoへアクセスするとhttps://www.google.com/search?q=arduinoへリダイレクトされるようです](http://www.google.com/search?q=arduino%E3%81%B8%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B9%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8https://www.google.com/search?q=arduino%E3%81%B8%E3%83%AA%E3%83%80%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99)。
このコードがこのリダイレクト動作に対応していないから動かないのではないでしょうか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます｡
質問内容を間違えていました｡client.connect(mac)ではなく正しくはEthernet.begin(mac)の箇所でした｡申し訳ありません｡